# Extract Big length string from XML response using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to extract token from XML response using regular expression but big length strings are failing to extract.

I am able to extract all values except authToken using regular expression (.+)

Please let me know any other solutions

```
     <ns1:minimumPINLength>6</ns1:minimumPINLength>
     <ns1:maximumPINLength>12</ns1:maximumPINLength>
     <ns1:minMediaPort>50000</ns1:minMediaPort>
     <ns1:maxMediaPort>50100</ns1:maxMediaPort>
     <ns1:vrProxyConfig>AUTO</ns1:vrProxyConfig>
   <ns1:authToken>eTJWbUpDajAyUHAzekNpNWdnZC9jdz09OkZuWHlqa21zS3NzQlRNVlZsUXVkWHc9PQ==</ns1:authToken>
```

Comment: nothing is failing
<ns1:authToken>(.+)</ns1:authToken>

Answer (score 0):

It should be a problem to extract the `authToken` with regular expression like:

```
<ns1:authToken>(.+?)</ns1:authToken>
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Regex Auth Token]

See [JMeter Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) and [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet) for details.

Also be aware that it makes more sense to use [XPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) for working with XML response types.